# How to completely disable javascript validation in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, client-side

I want to write all the code that will be sent to the browser to have it under my complete control.

For this I need to completely disable javascript validation that is provided with aps.net mvc.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but try changing the values in the web.config for the "ClientValidationEnabled" and "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" to false:

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It should be in your <appSettings>, if it's not, add it in. make sure it's the global web.config, not the one inside the views folder.